# A RenderFlex overflowed by 93 pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

[image]

```
Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                height: 55,
                width: 200,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black,width: 2)
                ),
                child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                  child: DropDownField(
                    value: value,
                    enabled: true,
                    items: locationItem,
                    itemsVisibleInDropdown: 2,
                    onValueChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        this.value = value!;
                        locationId = value;
                        print(value);
                        print(locationId);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
```

I have tried Singlechildscrollerview also
any answer regarding this:

Comment: change the container height

Answer (score 2):

Try below code hope its help to you. Refer DropdownButton-class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html)

Variable declaration:

```
String dropdownValue = 'One';
```

Your Widget:

```
 Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        height: 55,
        width: 200,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 2)),
        child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: DropdownButton<String>(
            value: dropdownValue,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
            elevation: 16,
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
            onChanged: (String newValue) {
              setState(() {
                dropdownValue = newValue;
              });
            },
            items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
                .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Your Dropdown-> [image]

Your dropdown after selecting-> [image]